# How to change top layout in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

When I need to change an activity skin, can I change top layout while maintaining the activity?

like... change orientation of display.

For example,

I have 1 activity file,
`MainActivity.java`

and I have 2 layout xmls,
`main_a.xml` 
`main_b.xml`

My start activity is `main_a.xml`

In this situation, Can I change layout as `main_b.xml` programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy

```
setContentView(main_b.xml);
```

If you have 2 different layouts for portrait and landscape - it is even easier - just place landscape layout file into `layout-land` folder (not `layout`) - and your layout will be applied automatically during orientation change

Comment: oh..  
Thank you so much.  
I thought,   
setContentView() can be used only once. haha